# Error in Query of Query; Coldfusion 8

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I'm running the following Query of Query and getting an error:

Timestamp: Name of the column which is holding all date and time related values.

MyDatabase: Name of the database

Events:    Name of another column with the name "Events" holding various values like, FIRST, SECOND,THIRD etc. I have mentioned FIRST here for 
convinience and clarity.

```
<cfquery datasource = "XX.XX.X.XX" name="master">
SELECT count(Timestamp) as COUNT,date_format(Timestamp,'%m-%d-%Y') 
FROM MyDatabase
WHERE EVENTS = "FIRST" GROUP BY Timestamp ;

 </cfquery> 


<cfquery dbtype="query" name="detail">

SELECT  *
FROM master 
WHERE Timestamp > <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> AND Timestamp <  <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">;


</cfquery>
```

As far as the startdate and enddate parameters are concerned, I have set them as follows:

```
<cfparam name="form.startdate" default="#dateformat(now()-5, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#">
<cfparam name="form.enddate" default="#dateformat(now()-1, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#">
<cfparam name="form.selectdate" default="#dateformat(now(), 'mm/dd/yyyy')#">
```

I'm getting the folowign error:

```
Error Executing Database Query.

Query Of Queries syntax error.
Encountered "Timestamp. Incorrect conditional expression, Expected one of [like|null|between|in|comparison] condition,

The error occurred in line 40

38 : SELECT  *
39 : FROM master 
40 : WHERE Timestamp > <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> AND Timestamp <  <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">;
41 :  
42 :
```

Could anyone tell me what went wrong?

---

**Update:**

After fixing the `#` sign, I am now getting the following error:

```
Error Executing Database Query.

Query Of Queries syntax error.
Encountered "Timestamp. Incorrect conditional expression, Expected one of [like|null|between|in|comparison] condition, 

The error occurred in line 40

38 : SELECT  *
39 : FROM master 
40 : WHERE Timestamp > <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> AND Timestamp <  <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">;
41 :  
42 :
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `value="#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate#)"`

Your closing `#` sign is misplaced. It should be *after* the closing parenthesis:

```
   value="#dateAdd('d', 1, form.enddate)#"
```

**Update:**

"Timestamp" and "Count" are bad choices for a column name or alias because they are reserved words in many databases. As Adrian mentioned in the comments, [both are reserved words in CF QoQ's as well.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff0.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7008). To use "Timestamp" in your QoQ, you must escape it by enclosing it in `[]`. In the long term, you are better off renaming the columns and avoiding the issue altogether.

```
 WHERE   [Timestamp] >= <cfqueryparam ....>
 AND     [Timestamp] <  <cfqueryparam ....>
```

As an aside, there is a *slight* bug in your SQL comparison. The end date operator should be `<`. By using `<=` the comparison includes an extra minute, so there is a slight chance it will pick up extra records ie `dateAdd('d', 1, form.enddate)` at midnight. The correct comparison is:

```
  WHERE   Timestamp >= <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> 
  AND     Timestamp <  <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">;
```

Comment: I updated my post but still getting an error. Please take a look at the new error. Thanks

Comment: COUNT is also a reserved word.

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo - Yep, good catch. I was focused on the error and overlooked the earlier query. Answer updated.

Comment: @Leigh @ iKnowKungFoo Thanks guys, I changed both the words, that is Timestamp to Timedetail and COUNT to Occurances. It worked. Could you tell me does the complier compares on the basis of date when month and year are same and on the basis of month when date and year are same?

Comment: @Leigh Could you please take a look at my updated question? Thanks !

Comment: @Tan - Lol, you have to stop piling multiple questions into one thread. S.O. is not a forum. It is a Q&A site, so only one question per thread. (That makes it easy for people to find answers quickly.) This one was answered. Close it out and open a new thread for your new question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your code.

```
#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate#)
```

should be:

```
#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate)#
```

Comment: I updated my post but still getting an error. Please take a look at the new error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the BETWEEN keyword?

So:

```
WHERE Timestamp > <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> AND Timestamp <  <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">;
```

Would become:

```
WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" /> AND <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" />;
```

Just as an alternative?

Comment: In this context, `BETWEEN` is inclusive, so technically it is not equivalent to your first statement, or the one in the OP.